# Research in computational neuroscience or computational medicine in Europe

Tags: research-process, mathematics, europe, research-topic, biology

How popular is research in computational neuroscience, or computational medicine in (mainland) Europe? I'm aware that INRIA in France does some good work, but do you know any other such groups and what kind or topic of research do they so? Many thanks!

Comment: Paris Descartes University is a popular place for neurosciences

Answer (score 1):

For computational neuroscience in germany, the website of the National Bernstein Network Computational Neuroscience (http://www.nncn.de/en) might be a good ressource for you. 
They list groups that are part of the Network, distinguishing between "centers" "groups" and "collaborations - i assume corresponding to scale of their involvement in computational neuroscience.

Comment: Thank you, and thanks also for the link! Do you happen to know any such place in Switzerland, Belgium, France or Luxembourg?

Answer (score 1):

The Gatsby institute in London does very good computational neuroscience research.
http://gatsby.ucl.ac.uk

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know any such place in Switzerland, Belgium, France or Luxembourg?